# Naming Principal Components in screeplot

Tags: r, pca

I am performing some PCA analysis using morphological measurements that were normalized using log10. I used the following command to generate the PCA in R:

```
    library(factoextra)
    PCA_morpho <- prcomp(dataframe_morpho, scale = TRUE)
```

After this I made a screeplot to see which components explain the variances obtained using the following command:

```
fviz_screeplot(PCA_morpho)
```

The printed plot is here:
[PCA_Screeplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyHq0.png)

Is it possible to know which inputs variables (from my "dataframe_morpho") compose each "Dimension" in this screeplot? Each "Dimension" could be each one of the measures from my data?

Comment: Try `PCA_morpho` at the command line. That will run the command `print(PCA_morpho)` and print report showing the factor loadings for each component.

Comment: Hi @Kaleb Pretto Gatto, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fviz_contrib()` to visualize the contribution of each variable to each dimension. From the manual:

> This function can be used to visualize the contribution of rows/columns from the results of Principal Component Analysis (PCA), Correspondence Analysis (CA), Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA), Factor Analysis of Mixed Data (FAMD), and Multiple Factor Analysis (MFA) functions.

Demo of its use here under "Variable contributions to the principal axes":

https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/factoextra/index.html